# Ubuntu on Nexus 7 and XBMC login

Tags: nexus-7

I tried to install XBMC on the Nexus 7 but when I logged out of Ubuntu and into XBMC the screen went blank with only a cursor visible.

No problem, I thought, I will just reboot the Nexus 7 but I have auto-login setup so it just tries to boot into XBMC again.

I'm now stuck, unable to boot into Ubuntu.
I presumed my only way out IDF to reinstall, this time without auto login.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, do a fresh installation and if you need a guide here's how to do that:

http://www.devicemondo.com/how-to/install-ubuntu-on-google-nexus-7/